# Inline-block elements stacking vertically in FF/IE, horizontal in Chrome?

Tags: css

```
<div class="content-top" style="width: 990px">
    <div style="width: 722px; margin-right: 20px" class="left-middle"></div>
    <div style="width: 200px" class="right"></div>
</div>
```

div.left-middle and div.right are both inline-block elements.  In Chrome, they appear next to each other horizontally, like I want them to.  In the newest Firefox and all versions of IE, div.left-middle is on top of div.right.  No margin/padding, so there's plenty of space for div.right.  I've tried making the width of div.left-middle incredibly small just to see if div.right would go back up there, it won't.  Any idea why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: Given that you've not shown the `display` property in the in-line CSS, could you please show us the CSS you're using? And a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding

```
.content-top { white-space: nowrap; }
.content-top > div { white-space: normal; }
```

this should costrain your div to stay aligned side by side

Comment: Worked wonderfully.  I had originally put white-space: nowrap on .content-top and it screwed up the text, didn't think of white-space normal on the child divs.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
float: left;
```

to your div's style. This will make your divs float next to each other.

Comment: I originally had them floated, but I need the height to be set by the contents, so floats won't work.